# Windows multitasking breaks OpenCL perfomance

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, opencl

I'm writing Qt application with simple idea: there are several OpenCL-capable devices, each of them gets own control thread which preparing data, executing OpenCL kernel and processing results. OpenCL code is actually bitcoin mining kernel (for now it's [this one](https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm/blob/master/phatk.cl), but it doesn't matter).

When working with 2 GPUs everything is ok.
When I use GPU and CPU there is a problem. CPU works at reasonable speed, but GPU slowing down to zero perfomance.

There are no such promblem under Linux. Under Windows, poclbm behaves in the same way: when starting multiple instances (1 for GPU, 1 for CPU), GPU perfomance is 0.

I'm not sure about which part of code I should post, so it will be helpfull. I can only mention, that thread is a `QThread`'s child with `run()` reimplemented with a busy loop `while( !_stop ) { mineBitcoins(); }`. Logic of that loop is pretty much copied from poclbm's `BitcoinMiner::mining_thread` ([here](https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm/blob/master/BitcoinMiner.py)).

In which direction should I dig? Thanks.

upd:
I'm using [QtOpenCL](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/opencl-snapshot/index.html) with [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the kernel on the CPU with full utilization of all cores, the threads that handle the other devices might not be able to keep up with the GPU, effectively limiting performance.

Try decreasing the number of threads running the kernel on the CPU, e.g. if your program runs on a quad-core with hyper threading, limit the threads to 7.

Comment: So, the reason is Windows multitasking?

Comment: its load balancing. its a provider-consumer problem. You can see your host device as a provider, providing data and commands for the CL devices. If it is not fast enough the command stream on the CL device stalls and it runs idle. If you use the host device as CL device it may not be able to maintain a constant command stream for other devices. This is highly usecase dependent and also depends on how many CL devices you have to feed etc.

Comment: mbien explained it nicely. As for why it works on Linux, I can only speculate. Maybe the Linux implementation of your SDK does a better job at allocating CPU power to the main thread, or POSIX threads don't allow thread priorities that effectively stall other threads with lower priority.

Answer (score 1):

don't use the host device as opencl device. If you really have too, restrict the amount of compute units (of the CPU used as host) allocated for CL by creating a subdevice.

Comment: Not using CPU helps, but I want to know the reason of such behaviour and the reason why it's different on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using the both devices in the same context. But if that is the case,  the memory consistency inside a context can be your problem and how the different OpenCL implementation handle it.

OpenCL tries to mantain the memory inside a context updated (at least in Windows), and can cause the GPU to continuosly copy the memory used back to "CPU-side".

I tryed that long ago and resulted as in your case with "~=0 performance in the GPU".